# Dreamweaver 5.5 - Phonegap / Android App - open urls within app

Tags: html, cordova, dreamweaver

I am building a HTML5 app via Dreamweaver 5.5 and want to use the childbrowser plugin to display a url internally - can anyone offer any advice on to do this? I'm struggling to implement. Or an alternative method to display a url within an app rather than safari?

cheers
paul

Comment: I ask a similar question, maybe the answer is useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429039/how-display-data-from-urlcross-domain-on-div-using-dreamweaver-phonegap